# Does release of nicotine from tobacco require combustion, or an open flame?

Tags: combustion

I am interested in the combustion argument Phillip Morris is making regarding its iqos product. They claim there's no combustion in their product but how do you take nicotine out of something without a combustion process? Enough heat would still create a chemical reaction... I'm asking based on a lawsuit they have going on. Is it possible to say there's zero combustion in a product that heats a material to extract a chemical(nicotine) in its vapor smoke?

Comment: From what I've just read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heated_tobacco_product), nicotine is released from tobacco at only 150 Celsius. Combustion occurs at 750 Celsius. The heated-tobacco products (iQOS is one of them) appear to target 350 Celsius, which is when pyrolysis occurs but is far lower than the combustion temperature.

Comment: Pure nicotine has a well-defined boiling point and can be vaporized just by heating it up. No chemical reaction or combustion is involved in that.

Comment: Hope my edits retained the intended original sense of the question. Feel free to roll back to the previous version otherwise. Also, please add references (or links to sources) where possible.